# how to calculate the future in a past period? pine script

Tags: future

I am trying to convert to pine script the following thinkscript indicator which checks and calculates a current value based in past periods (where available data is available) and I have not found out how to do it as in pine script it is not allowed for negative values. I am sure there is a way to overcome this but for that I need your help. Thanks in advance

this is the code I tried and is saved with no problems but when executing I get the message:
"Invalid number of bars back [-1] within the history-referencing operator. The value must be >=0."

```
 //@version=5
 indicator("My script")
 price = close
 length = 5
 disp = (-length/2)+1
 dprice = price[disp]
 ww = ta.sma( dprice , length)
 var tmp1 = 0.0
 tmp1 := na(dprice) ? (2 * tmp1[1] - tmp1[2]) : ww
 tmp = na(price) ? na : tmp1
 plot(tmp)
```